# Project Euler #12: find smallest triangular number with over 500 factors

Tags: julia, factors

My code in Julia, almost identical to the Python code (see below), runs in 4.6 s while the Python version runs in 2.4 s. Obviously there is a lot or room for improvement.

```
function Problem12()
    #=
     The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural
    numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be:
    1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28.

    The first ten terms would be:
    1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

    Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

     1: 1
     3: 1,3
     6: 1,2,3,6
    10: 1,2,5,10
    15: 1,3,5,15
    21: 1,3,7,21
    28: 1,2,4,7,14,28

    We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

    What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred
    divisors?
    =#

    function num_divisors(n)
        res = floor(sqrt(n))
        divs = []
        for i in 1:res
            if n%i == 0
                append!(divs,i)
            end
        end
        if res^2 == n
            pop!(divs)
        end
        return 2*length(divs)
    end

    triangle = 0
    for i in Iterators.countfrom(1)
        triangle += i
        if num_divisors(triangle) > 500
            return string(triangle)
        end
    end
end
```

Python version below:

```
import itertools
from math import sqrt, floor


# Returns the number of integers in the range [1, n] that divide n.
def num_divisors(n):
    end = floor(sqrt(n))
    divs = []
    for i in range(1, end + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            divs.append(i)
    if end**2 == n:
        divs.pop()
    return 2*len(divs)


def compute():
    triangle = 0
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        # This is the ith triangle number, i.e. num = 1 + 2 + ... + i =
        # = i*(i+1)/2
        triangle += i
        if num_divisors(triangle) > 500:
            return str(triangle)
```

Comment: What are compiler options for julia? Are you using interactive mode?

Comment: Not sure about that. I'm just running vanilla Julia in VSCode

Comment: Check it. Also how do you measure time?

Comment: The big performance killer is due to `res` being a floating-point number. Replace `res = floor(sqrt(n))` by `res = isqrt(n)` and you should get an order of magnitude improvement in speed. I'll write up an answer that includes this.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to add a short summary of the problem statement?  You can keep the link as a reference, but your question does need to be complete even if the linked material isn't accessible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The performance discrepancy in your Julia code comes from

```
res = floor(sqrt(n))  # is a Float64
```

which is a floating-point number (specifically, Float64) due to `sqrt`. This causes the loop variable `i` to be a Float64 as well, leading to a massive slowdown when you test for divisibility via taking the modulus `(if n%i == 0`) because Euclidean division (i.e., `mod`/`rem` and `div`/`fld`/`cld`) is very slow for floats. It is much faster for integers.

Furthermore, this does not always give the mathematically correct answer due to the inherently limited precision of floats. For example,

```
julia> Int(floor(sqrt(67108865^2 - 1)))
67108865
```

Instead, you should call `isqrt` to take the integer square root

```
res = isqrt(n)  # is an Int
```

which also gives the exact answer

```
julia> isqrt(67108865^2 - 1)
67108864
```

Avoid `Int(floor(sqrt(n)))` and `floor(Int, sqrt(n))` due to the limited precision outlined above.

Comment: The biggest performance issue is not isqrt vs sqrt, it's using trial division instead of a better factorisation method.

Comment: @EmilyL. Thanks, I've edited my answer to clarify what it answers. Note that the OP's question is why their translated Julia code is slower than their Python code. The answer as explained is that the inner loop in the Julia code is taking floating-point modulus (via `libc`'s `fmod`) whereas the Python code is taking integer modulus, ultimately because `floor(sqrt(n))` is a float in Julia.  The solution is to use `isqrt(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're applying a brute force solution by counting all the divisors through trial division. This is excessively slow and we can do better.

First, realize that all integers can be written as a product of prime numbers (the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)). Equivalently it can be written as a list of powers of the prime numbers.

I.e: any integer \$n\$ can be written as \$n = \prod p_i^{k_i}\$ where \$p_i\$ is a prime number and \$k_i\$ is an integer.

Note further that a "triangle number" is just the arithmetic sum from 1 to n.

So we're looking for \$n\$ such that \$n(n+1)/2 = \prod p_i^{k_i}\$ under the condition that \$\prod k_i+1 > 500\$. Note here that product of powers plus one computes the number of ways you can pick zero (the +1) to all of the powers of a prime to contribute to a number, which is the number of divisors you can have.

Your program would then be something like this:

1. Generate large list of primes using a prime sieve or hard code.
2. For each n starting at 1, compute the "triangle number", do prime factorisation using the list of primes; this is our speed-up - we only need to try dividing by known primes. Then count the prime powers, compute their product to get the divisors and check if larger than 500.

This will be faster than OP's code because we only test division with known primes rather than with all integers.

You might be able to do some fancy math to determine a better starting point than n=1 in step 2 by using the expressions above, but that's left as an academic exercise for the reader.

Comment: Using some of these tricks (and a few more, mainly that `gcd(n, n+1)==1)` which allows you to factor the triangular number by factoring `n` and `n+1`), I have the time down to .5ms for `Problem12(500)` (or half a second for  `Problem12(5000)`

`
using Primes
function Problem12(n)
    n < 2 && return 1
    prev_num_fact = 1
    for i in Iterators.countfrom(3)
        i = iseven(i) ? i>>1 : i
        num_fact = prod(e+1 for (p, e) in eachfactor(i))
        if num_fact*prev_num_fact > n
            return i-1
        end
        prev_num_fact = num_fact
    end
end
`

Answer (score 1):

You need the number of divisors, not divisors. So you don't need to gather all divisors, just remember the count. Increase it by 1 instead of push!/append, decrease instead of pop/

Comment: Thx for your answer! Although your suggestions do help in terms of allocations, they don't help in terms of performance :(